Kernel32.dll LoadLibrary does not work in Docker container
I am developing a .NET WebApi Application which is intended to make calls to a Windows dll library. I use kernel32.dll's function LoadLibrary to load the dll. When I run the application on IIS or IIS Express on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019 it works fine. When I run it in Docker container (Windows) it generates error 126 which means the dll file does not exist, though System.IO.File.Exists returns true.
Here is the code of the sample controller which I created to debug this error:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DllLoadTest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DllLoadTestController(ILogger<DllLoadTestController> logger) : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DllLoadTestController> _logger = logger;

        [HttpGet(Name = "LoadFanSelectDll")]
        public string GetFanSelect()
        {
            string dllPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "FanSelectDll", "FANselect.dll");
            string result;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(dllPath))
            {
                IntPtr fanSelectDllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
                result = fanSelectDllHandle != IntPtr.Zero ? $"Dll handle: {fanSelectDllHandle}" : $"Error: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Error: dll file does not exist.";
            }
            return result;
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);
    }
}

Here is the contents of the dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DllLoadTest/DllLoadTest.csproj", "DllLoadTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DllLoadTest/DllLoadTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DllLoadTest"
RUN dotnet build "./DllLoadTest.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DllLoadTest.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DllLoadTest.dll"]

The test project is available on github:
https://github.com/antares-17/DllLoadTest
I would appriciate any help.

Are both .dll's the same bitness? (32/64bit)

Yes, both are 64-bit

could you try to print dllPath to see if the path is correct or not. add ServerCore.AppCompatibility feature in the Dockerfile. run this commanddocker exec -it <container_id> cmd   dir C:\app\FanSelectDll to check  DLL is correctly placed in the Docker container

The dll path is correct, I check it before the call to LoadLibrary:
if (System.IO.File.Exists(dllPath))
Though it is not "C:\app\FanSelectDll". Currently it is "C:\app\bin\Debug\net8.0\FanSelectDLL" since I run the application under VisualStudio debug on DockerDescktop

The error "DLL not found" may refer to a dependency of your library. Check out loader snaps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1359836/using-gflags-show-loader-snaps-with-visual-studio
